# "Import in body of module; reorder to top import/first" ESLint (ReactJs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

When compiling my ReactJs code I get the following error import/first error:

[image]

The solutions presented in [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600727/create-react-app-failed-to-compile-import-first-error) don't seem to work for me.

The `../recharts/es6/index.js` file looks something like this:

```
import _Brush from './cartesian/Brush';
export { _Brush as Brush };
import _ReferenceLine from './cartesian/ReferenceLine';
export { _ReferenceLine as ReferenceLine };
import _ReferenceDot from './cartesian/ReferenceDot';
export { _ReferenceDot as ReferenceDot };
import _ReferenceArea from './cartesian/ReferenceArea';
export { _ReferenceArea as ReferenceArea };
```

My question, therefore, how does one disable the import/first rule for ESLint? 
Or might the error be due to something else entirely?

Comment: Try to reorder all your `import`s first then all `export`s. Btw  you can use this syntax `export { _Brush as Brush } from '../my/folder'` without needs to use `import`

Comment: There are about 50 such import export pairs in that file. And even if I do it for this file, the same error just pops up again for some other file.

Comment: Check out [`import\order`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/order.md) & [`import\first`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/first.md) eslint rules. Anyway `/* eslint-disable import/first */` will help you

Comment: @TheReason would this go in the beginning of the index.js file itself?

Comment: in the beginning of your file `// import/first : 0`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116197/react-redux-import-in-body-of-module-reorder-to-top-import-first/57255275#57255275

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved this error in one of my auto generated files. In my `.ts` source file the import rule (any and all imports must be at the top of the file) was followed but the generated `.js` had imports after some polyfills so I added this line to the top of my file to get around it:
`/* eslint-disable import/first */`

*note: the comments have already mentioned this solution. just adding this so the question can have an answer.